# How to checkout from SVN with Oomph?

Tags: eclipse, svn, oomph

I try to write a *Setup Project Model* which installs Eclipse and also checks out the source code from SVN with Oomph 1.6.0.

I read [Automating Project-specific Eclipse Setups with Oomph](https://timdelbruegger.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/automating-project-specific-eclipse-setups-with-oomph/):

> One big issue in the process of software development (especially, but not only for bigger teams) is the setup of a common IDE. There are many settings and Plugins that must be common to all project members:
>
> - File encodings
> - Target Platforms
> - SCM-Linking to Git/SVN/CVS/…

so it seems possible. But I couldn't find any documentation for it.

I found under *Additional Tasks* and *Git Clone...* an extension for Git, but there is no extension for SVN.

I found [Importing project set from SVN fails](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1067968/):

> I'd like to implement a setup task which creates a set of projects defined with a team project set:
>
> ```xml
> <setupTask xsi:type="projectset:ProjectSetImportTask" uRL="https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/MYPROJECT/user.psf">
>     <description>User projects</description>
> </setupTask>
> ```

I set the property [`url`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.doc/javadoc/org/eclipse/oomph/setup/projectset/ProjectSetImportTask.html#getURL()), but the task is not executed. With the help of the referenced [link](https://github.com/joergreichert/oomph-catalogue):

> - With Help -> Perform Setup Tasks... you can manually trigger the setup tasks again

I could excute the task manually, but I got an exception:

```
Performing Project Set Import svn://svn.mycompany.com/repo/test
org.eclipse.oomph.util.IOExceptionWithCause: unknown protocol: svn: svn://svn.mycompany.com/repo/test
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createIOException(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:527)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.access$14(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:514)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$ConnectionHandler.process(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1536)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:302)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projectset.impl.ProjectSetImportTaskImpl$Helper.getXMLContent(ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:296)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projectset.impl.ProjectSetImportTaskImpl$Helper.isNeeded(ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:247)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projectset.impl.ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.isNeeded(ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:219)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.initNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:1809)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:675)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$5(SetupUIPlugin.java:414)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:253)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: svn
  at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URI.toURL(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.identity.FileTransferID.getURL(FileTransferID.java:78)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:877)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:576)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$InputStreamConnectionHandler.sendConnectionRequest(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1640)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$ConnectionHandler.process(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1391)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:302)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projectset.impl.ProjectSetImportTaskImpl$Helper.getXMLContent(ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:296)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projectset.impl.ProjectSetImportTaskImpl$Helper.isNeeded(ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:247)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projectset.impl.ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.isNeeded(ProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:219)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.initNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:1809)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:675)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$5(SetupUIPlugin.java:414)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:253)
  ... 1 more
```

How can I check out my source code automatically with Oomph 1.6.0?

Comment: Any success since your question about automated SVN checkout ? (i'm wondering if this is possible and working flawlessly). Have found for example this configuration example that let me think that it should be possible : https://github.com/nonfuncter/oomph-svn-checkout/blob/master/OomphSVNCheckout.setup

Comment: @SRG: No. I think SVN protocol is not supported, only HTTP. Unfortunately, my server doesn't support HTTP, only SVN. Your refered example uses HTTP not SVN, right?

Comment: Right, the provided link is only about HTTP SVN url !